# If-else not work properly when use Facebook Interstitial Ad, interstitial ad shows automatically

Tags: java, android-studio, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

`if-else` used for check is `interstitial ad` loaded or not. If not loaded then `startIntent` by `else`. (code is below).

**Problem(see Logcat):** If *Ad not loaded* then `second activity` open via `else` part then after some seconds `AdListener` run that is in `if` part `Interstitial ad` pop-up **automatically**. [this is against to Ad policy]

```
2020-11-22 01:26:46.761 12278-12278/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/HomeActivity: ===== BTN 1 ELSE PART
2020-11-22 01:26:48.631 12278-12278/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/HomeActivity: ===== AdListener : Ad loaded and then show.
2020-11-22 01:26:48.731 12278-12470/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.trace.perf"
2020-11-22 01:26:48.844 12278-12278/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/HomeActivity: ===== loggin impression
2020-11-22 01:26:58.141 12278-12314/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12278-7] setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: 2 dequeued buffers would exceed the maxBufferCount (2) (maxAcquired 1 async 0 mDequeuedBufferCannotBlock 0)
2020-11-22 01:26:58.141 12278-12314/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/Surface: IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(3) returned Invalid argument
2020-11-22 01:26:58.146 12278-12314/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12278-8] setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: 2 dequeued buffers would exceed the maxBufferCount (2) (maxAcquired 1 async 0 mDequeuedBufferCannotBlock 0)
2020-11-22 01:26:58.146 12278-12314/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/Surface: IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(3) returned Invalid argument
2020-11-22 01:26:58.151 12278-12314/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-12278-9] setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: 2 dequeued buffers would exceed the maxBufferCount (2) (maxAcquired 1 async 0 mDequeuedBufferCannotBlock 0)
2020-11-22 01:26:58.151 12278-12314/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/Surface: IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(3) returned Invalid argument
2020-11-22 01:27:50.611 12278-12278/com.udai.aadharloan.kredit.finance.pmscheme E/HomeActivity: ===== Ad dismissed.
```

**Here `else` part run then new activity open. Then automatically run `AdListener`  that in `If`part.(like:onAdLoaded, onLoggingImpression,onInterstitialDismissed)**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn1Home:
                if (interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "===== btn 1: if part running");
                    interstitialAd=new InterstitialAd(this,"166868475011030_166000348414076");
                    interstitialAdListener=new InterstitialAdListener(){
                        @Override public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad){}
                        @Override public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad){
                            Log.e(TAG, "===== Ad dismissed.");
                            Intent intent1btn=new Intent(HomeActivity.this,page1activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent1btn);}
                        @Override public void onError(Ad ad,AdError adError){}
                        @Override public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad){
                            Log.e(TAG, "===== AdListener : Ad loaded and then show.");
                            interstitialAd.show();}
                        @Override public void onAdClicked(Ad ad){}
                        @Override public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad){Log.e(TAG, "===== loggin impression");}};
                    // For auto play video ads, it's recommended to load the ad
                    // at least 30 seconds before it is shown
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialAd.buildLoadAdConfig().withAdListener(interstitialAdListener).build());

                }else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "===== BTN 1 ELSE PART");
                        if (!interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
                            interstitialAd.loadAd();
                            Intent intent1btn = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, page1activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent1btn);
                        }
                }

                break;
.........
```

How can i solve this facebook interstitial ad problem?

Comment: Try this, maybe its helpful: `if (interstitialAd != null){ //your code for adLoaded}`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem:

Do not call  `interstitialAd.show()` in `onAdLoaded(Ad ad)`.

It call just after before `AdListener` mean before `Log.e(TAG, "===== btn 1: if part running")`

Comment: Bro, your answer is wrong. If you show `ad` before `AdListener` then `ad` will show. But on that `ad` this `AdListener` not work. Mean if you not show `ad` in `onAdloaded()` then `addismiss()` method not work in `Facebook-audience-network` .